# Unit Test: Cannot get value from Service in Java

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to test the following method that gets data from `Price` service.

***CountryServiceImpl:***

```
public PriceDTO findBCountryUuid(UUID countryUuid) {
        
        // code omitted

    // !!! currency value is null
        Currency currency = currencyService.getCurrencyByCountry(countryUuid);
        
        return new PriceDTO(currency);
}
```

Here is the `PriceService`.

***PriceServiceImpl:***

```
@Override
public Currency getCurrencyByCountry(UUID countryUuid) {
        return countryRepository.findByUuid(countryUuid)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Country"))
                        .getCurrency();
}
```

I use the following approach to test:

```
@Mock
private CountryRepository countryRepository;

@Mock
private CurrencyServiceImpl currencyService;
        
@InjectMocks
private CountryServiceImpl priceService;


@Test
public void test_findBCountryUuid() {
        
        // code omitted 

        final Country country = new Country();
        country.setName("Country");
        country.setCurrency(currency);
        
        when(countryRepository.findByUuid(countryUuid))
            .thenReturn(Optional.of(country));

        PriceDTO result = priceService.findBCountryUuid(countryUuid);
        
        //... assertions        
}
```

The problem is that; In the `findBCountryUuid` method, the `currency` value is null, and for this reason I get null price value in the `result` parameter of my tets method.
The problem is completely related to using wrong mocking or annotation related to the `PriceService`. I think I should mock the repo that `PriceService` uses instead of mocking `PriceService`. What is wrong with this implementation?

Comment: Show us the complete code(if not sensitive), its little unclear from above code snippet how these classes looks like.

Comment: You are mocking behavior for the repository which will never be called because you are mocking the `PriceService`. You should register the behavior on the `CurrencyService` not the repository.

Comment: @M.Deinum Any example please about what you try to mean?

Comment: If you want to offend me. The answer is even too short I would say as it only states the how, not the why. So yo u have a solution but no clue on why that should be that way and thus will not really learn from it. So no that is actually not a good answer. Also I didn't receive 100K+ reputation by giving crap answers to users but dedicated and elaborate answers explaining the why and the how. Which is how a good answer should be written.

Comment: @Medium If you try to use some code in your letters, you may get 500+ K. I suggest not using letters or stories in your answers :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mock the behaviour for the method `PriceServiceImpl.getCurrencyByCountry`

```
PriceServiceImpl priceServiceMock = Mockito.mock(PriceServiceImpl.class);
Mockito.when(priceServiceMock.getCurrencyByCountry(any(UUID.class))).thenReturn(new Currency()); // Return either a newly instantiated object or a mockek one based on your need
```

Comment: You rock!.. Thanks a lot. I hope some user see this short and good answer and try to give such kind of answers instead of writing letter :)

Comment: Any idea regarding to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70606351/junit-how-to-test-update-methods)**?